# How to interpret if $\sum_{j = 0}^{n} \frac {1}{j!}$ is a stable algorithm for computing $e$?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

[Crosspost](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40323/how-to-interpret-if-displaystyle-sum-j-0n-frac-1j-is-a-stable-a/40325?noredirect=1#comment78215_40325)

I am trying to solve problem $15.1$ from *Numerical Linear Algebra* by Trefethen and Bau, which reads

> Determine whether the algorithm is backward stable, stable but not backward stable, or unstable.
>
> Data: None. Solution: $e$, computed by summing  $\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{j!}$ from left to right, and stopping when a summand is reached of magnitude < $\epsilon_{machine}.$

Now, the definition of backward stability given in the book is that for a problem $f$ with data space $X$, an algorithm $\tilde f$ is stable if for all $x$ there exists an $\tilde x$ such that
$$||\tilde f(x) - f(\tilde x)|| = \mathcal O(\epsilon_m)$$
with $$||x - \tilde x|| / ||x|| = \mathcal O(\epsilon_m)$$

Since we have no "data", I am pretty confused on how to apply this definition. I am fairly certain that for a fixed $\epsilon_m$, $\tilde f(x)$  should be $\sum_{j = 0}^{n} \frac {1}{j!}$
where $n$ is the first summand less than $\epsilon_m$ (this has it's own problems, because the algorithm depends on $\epsilon_m$, which is weird). I am tempted to say $f(\tilde x)$ should be $e$ (even though it doesn't really match the definition) but that feels too much like forward-error analysis, which I know is distinct from stability. As far as interpreting $||x - \tilde x|| / ||x|| = \mathcal O(\epsilon_m)$, I am at a total loss.

I also thought of interpreting the problem space $X$ as all the set of all real number sequences, and $$f((a_k)_{k = 0}^{\infty}) = \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}a_k.$$
since at least it would give a way to interpret $||x - \tilde x|| / ||x||$. But I don't think this is right either, because I don't think we should vary the sequence itself.

Comment: Please avoid using `\displaystyle` when including mathematical content in the question title. See [Guidelines for good use of MathJax in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233) for more information.

Comment: @soupless Fixed

Comment: Please no cross posting without referencing the other post. If you feel that you must cross post, then make a link between the posts (https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/40323/19136)